# Error message linking a C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin project

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

`[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Variant::Exec(System::AutoCmd&, int) const' referenced from`

I am getting the above error message when I am trying to use the new 32-bit compiler in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin instead of the classic compiler.
This same piece of code compiles successfully using the classic compiler.

I know something is probably missing (a lib?), but what?

Any idea?

Comment: Did you create the project with VCL enabled?

Comment: It's an old project that was imported from XE2.

Comment: you should NEVER import projects from old versions. The import process *rarely* works properly. ALWAYS create a new project fresh, and then add your existing source files to it as needed.

Comment: It was imported like this. New project and them import forms one by one.

Comment: Well, then that goes back to my original question - when the project was created, was the VCL framework enabled for it?

Comment: I would have thought that the fact that it compiles ok using the "classic" compiler suggests that the project must be configured to use VCL.

Comment: If course it was. If I comment out those two Exec calls everythings compiles successfully.

Comment: In that case it might be helpful to include the code snippet which contains the two Exec calls.....

Comment: @gargalatas, did you manage to solve this issue? I'm having it with Builder 11 as well.

Comment: @some-dude Unfortuantely i can't remember. I use twine compiler anyway.

Comment: @gargalatas Thank you for the update. I'll post if I manage to fix it.